# Problem with getting irregular polygons from WKT data

Tags: qgis, polygon, well-known-text

[image: This is what I am getting, but want irregular polygons the way I drew them instead]I am quite new to QGIS, and am working with air pollution survey data from ODK. I have to correct the survey inaccuracies (in the WKT coordinate data) recorded by using satellite imagery as base layer.

The best way I've found to do this is to manually create new polygons/shapes from the vertices and manually capture the WKT data of each new feature.

The problem I am facing is that when I use the updated WKT data from a .csv and import it into QGIS, the areas marked are actually regular rectangles that are BBOX/extent type, ie, capture a regular rectangle around the otherwise irregular plotted area. Why is this happening? How can I get the actual irregular shapes that I myself drew on QGIS to correct the original survey WKT data.

Here is an example from my correct WKT column:

`POLYGON((80.83135413142666437 26.90884910335962132, 80.83069810082588447 26.90791175466728902, 80.83113553597212331 26.90747225490461148, 80.83136922362844246 26.90778337644801255, 80.83124752564707194 26.90786396933244617, 80.83150799810660203 26.90833256223242387, 80.83135582002505259 26.90884910537621977))`

I got this through the get WKT plug in.

Comment: please add an example of the WKT you are importing

Comment: Thank you for your response! Here is an example from my correct WKT column POLYGON((80.83135413142666437 26.90884910335962132, 80.83069810082588447 26.90791175466728902, 80.83113553597212331 26.90747225490461148, 80.83136922362844246 26.90778337644801255, 80.83124752564707194 26.90786396933244617, 80.83150799810660203 26.90833256223242387, 80.83135582002505259 26.90884910537621977))

I got this through the get WKT plug in

Comment: You should add this to your initial question by editing it - otherwise, it will remain closed. I added your comment to the question body. However, you workflow is still unclear: plese describe step by step what you do, otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: Please, describe the process to import the CSV with detail, because I was able to import your geometry and it isn't a rectangle.